# Как удалить .NET Framework 4.6?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-server

Вместе с Visual Studio 2015 RTM установил .NET Framework 4.6, в связи с чем получил кучу багов, связанных с Tail Call Optimization, отключение RyuJIT их не лечит - как мне удалить .NET Framework 4.6 и RyuJIT с машины полностью?

Два кейса - удалить с девелоперской машины (Windows 8.1) и удалить с билд-серверов (Windows Server 2012R2).

Comment: А что за баги с Tail Call?

Comment: @PashaPash https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1299 https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/536 https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1296 код, написанный на F# просто перестаёт работать, без ошибок и экзепшнов - строчки некоторые не выполняются, возвращаются неправильные значения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто скачать [.NET 4.6 Offline Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137), запустить - и выбрать опцию Remove.

Если без инсталлера - то откройте
Control Panel / Programs / Programs and Features / Installed Updates. 
Там найдите и удалите:

- KB3033095 для RC
- KB3045557 для RTM

Не уверен насчет точного номера - он не появляется при апгрейде через RC. Если не найдете KB3045557 - то ищите по дате установки.

Answer (score 3):

При попытке удалить фреймворк через инсталлер - мне сообщили какой именно апдейт нужно удалить: KB3045563 в моём случае.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137

> On Windows Vista SP2 / Windows 7 SP1/ Windows Server 2008 SP2 / Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, you will see the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 as an installed product under Programs and Features in Control Panel. • On Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 you can find this as Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3045562) under Installed Updates in Control Panel. • On Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2 you can find this as Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3045563) under Installed Updates in Control Panel.

В соответствии с этим, удалить нужно один из апдейтов:

- KB3045562
- KB3045563

Для более старых операционных систем .NET Framework 4.6 появится в установленных Programs and Features.